# How can I make my text closer to my header?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to make my small text closer to my bigger text? How do I do this?

**Some off my HTML**

```
<div class="header">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        
    <h1>Summit</h1>
    <p>Climb the summit, then simply sum it</p>

    </div>
```

**Some of my CSS**

```
.header h1 {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    Font-size: 70px;
    color: #22223b;
    margin-top: 300px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.header p {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    Font-size: 20px;
    color: #22223b;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid using `<br>`, especially several in a row. You barely need row-breaks in HTML nowadays. Used `padding` or `margin` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, `<h1>` tag gives margin by default. So, you can modify that in CSS.

Like,

```
header h1{
   margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to be specific, you can use `margin-bottom: 0;` instead of margin.

Comment: Did you mean `margin-bottom: 0` instead, because that is the margin responsible for the gap between `h1` and `p`? `marginTop` doesnt exist as CSS property.

Comment: yea, my mistake. we use camelcase inside react js.  I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

Each element in HTML has their own margin and border. The header elements usually have their `margin-bottom` CSS defined.

So you have 2 ways to do this: Either you can modify `<h1>` `margin-bottom` value. Or you can give `<p>` a negative martin-top value.

Option1:

```
.header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Option 2:

```
.header p {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the small text is the paragraph and the big text is the h1 but you did not specify how close... Adjust the margins and padding is usually a good start.

You can use a single definition to define both padding & margin - but supply 4 values (top,right,bottom,left)

```css
.header h1 {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  Font-size: 70px;
  color: #22223b;
  margin: 300px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}

.header p {
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  Font-size: 20px;
  color: #22223b;

  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
  margin: -1.5rem 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Summit</h1>
  <p>Climb the summit, then simply sum it</p>

</div>
```